# How to connect a button in storyboard to code in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, button, storyboard, connect

I have been coding since yesterday so this might seem like a stupid question:
My app is supposed to be a shopping list app where users can write down whatever they want to buy, add a date and then the list can be saved and later opened and deleted. I created a User Interface and now whenever I am trying to control - drag it into the view controller, the window to create an IB outlet does not appear. There are multiple answers for similar questions on here but none actually answers my problem. 
My questions are: How do I connect my button to code and how do I get the window to show up?
Also, I would like to let the user delete one Textfield at a time so that they can keep the other part of the list. Do I have to connect each textfield to its own delete button?

Every help or idea on how to fix this problem is much appreciated! 
I hope the screenshots attached will help to understand my problem. 
[image]
This is how my UI looks. I managed to connect the Edit shopping list button to the second scene. Now I would like to connect the Button "save list" to code so that I could write code that saves the users' data.
Whenever I try to link it, nothing shows up. Do I have to set an IBoutlet first? and how would I do that?

Comment: There are numerous tutorials available for doing this. Look one of them up.

Comment: Just pasted your question in youtube search and find this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AiKOvoRFOCM

Comment: None of these actually help me though.

Answer (score 0):

Give your button code:

`Button.TouchUpInside += (object Sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
//code here
}`

For the window to show up:

click (with ctrl) on the button and drag the mouse over to the page you want to open. Then select "show" in the small dialog.

Comment: It says "expected declaration". What now?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you don't need to set a IBOutlet first. You can create an Action without any problems.
2. I suggest you to use a TableView of 4 elements instead of 4 static  elements, so you can add/delete items from a list
3. Be sure you are selecting the button/editText you want to ctrl+drag to your swift code class, and be sure you're showing the right class(the one linked to the ViewController)

Comment: I don't really understand how this should work. How would I do it the way I saw it in tutorials (I managed to do it before with a different app) ?

Comment: What do you don't understand? The TableView?

Comment: Yes. I have not heard of this before.

Comment: Your question was not about a TableView tutorial. Just search on google for a good tutorial. Did you managed to bind actions?

Comment: I am trying to do it now. I will let you know what happened

Comment: I was not able to bind actions.

Comment: Try recreate the project, there might be a bug on that one

Comment: Did this error occurred after refactoring classes/storyboards? Did you moved them into another group?